# Download .zip file problem (downloading .php file)

Tags: php, file, download, zip

I want to download a .zip file, but when i go to download it, it forces me to download the .php file. I use this simple code that is all over the internet so I don't know why I can't download .zip file.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Content-type: application/zip");  
header('Content-length: '.filesize($fullpath));  
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($fullpath));  

readfile($fullpath);
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing it with?

Comment: are you sure you're not just downloading a zip file named .php?

Comment: Don't you need `filesize($fullfile)`?

Comment: I used full path in readfile(), changed that now

Comment: Your code works just fine now for me.

Comment: I've seen on one forum a thread with the same problem, but can't find that forum now:/

Comment: does regular php code work? e.g php file in the same path is interpreted?

Comment: yes, i've checked file path and php functions (basename, readfile) work fine just force me to download my download.php file, instead of .zip file :/

Comment: If all else fails you could add the filename to the end of the url. So /download.php?path=test.zip will become /download.php/test.zip?path=test.zip. This will make the browser think the page's filename is test.zip, not download.php. You could use mod_rewrite or some php code inspection $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to make the ?path= part superfluous  if you want you urls to look better, but is not necessary.

Comment: What exactly does the download.php file contain when you download it? The PHP source code?

Comment: Is $fullpath actually set? When empty it could cause some weird behaviour.

Comment: .php file that i'm forces to download is this very .php file with this code

Comment: $fullpath is set, i've tried it with $_GET['file'], and direct input like    $fullpath='path/myfile.zip';

Comment: ok, i'll search on the internet to find the answer, as i said i've seen the thread with the same issue but it was pretty long time ago and I thought i would never need it:/ Thanks guys for your help

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code, because it seems something else is causing $fullpath to be set to $PHP_SELF.

Comment: ".php file that i'm forces to download is this very .php file with this code" are you sure your server is even executing PHP?

Comment: ".php file that i'm forces to download is this very .php file with this code" - if you want to have it zipped, you need to implement zipping functions, not just setting the header.

Comment: @phpEnthusiast no, if your downloads contain the PHP source code, then your server is *not* executing PHP, at least not for that specific file. That is what you need to look into.

Comment: Hey Guys, this is an old thread but just wanted to know if someone figured out the exact problem?? I have a similar situation here... the file getting downloaded is the zip file but the name/ext of the file are .php file. The filename is generated on the server so I can't directly use "/download.php/test.zip?path=test.zip" @Gerben (which works in my case). Also, I am getting this error randomly.. sometimes it is downloaded as .zip but once it goes to .php it sticks with that no matter what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serving the PHP file with a .zip extension, getting the PHP source code for download is expected behaviour - ZIP files do not get parsed by the PHP interpreter by default.

You would have to register the ZIP extension to be parsed by PHP. That is pretty sub-optimal, though; in this case, you can link to the PHP file with the .php extension. The `filename` header will provide the correct name to the user who downloads the file.

If you are using a .php extension and the source code of your PHP file is served, your server configuration is broken.

Comment: You are confusing readfile with include. readfile doesn't try to interpret the file, like include. It just "Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer."

Comment: @Gerben read the comments before downvoting. *The whole PHP source code* gets downloaded and is never interpreted in the first place. Probably because he is using the .zip extension instead of .php

Comment: sorry, misread it
@phpEnthusiast wat is the filename of your php code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are downloading the zip file named as `.php`
try to open the downloaded file with `winzip` or `winrar`